# VSCode with WSL - How to use Bash for the launch configurations?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Visual Studio Code to develop a TypeScript Node application on Windows 10, with WSL enabled.

Thanks to [other](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6579) [threads](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24967), I'm almost able to run a VSCode task with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

But now I try to do the same with a *launch configuration*. How can I make a launch configuration to use the `node` executable *installed in WSL* instead of the one installed on Windows?

If I run this command directly in the integrated terminal, with Bash, it works :

```
node src/start.js
```

But when I press "`[F5]`" and start a launch configuration that runs this same file, I get an error : "*Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application*". This is because the `oracledb` library is used and has been compiled in Bash, not in Windows.

How can I make a launch configuration use Bash to run Node?

**UPDATE** :  I opened [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25033) about that on VSCode's GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

Not if sure you still need help.

- open bash outside of the vs code.
- then run the following command, to install node.

  `sudo apt install nodejs-legacy`

and you should be able to run node with bash in vs code.